# What storage device to use to daily write 10GB of temporary data?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, usb-flash-drive, sd-card, lifespan

I have a notebook that I also use to watch TV for 5 hours a day. I have the timeshift option activated so that I can go back.

I've calculated that the 2GB reserved space for timeshift is completely rewritten 5 times a day on average, so there are about 10GB of daily write operations.

I don't want to wear out my internal SSD, which happens to be a Crucial MX300 drive.  Assuming this drive is an average, consumer quality SSD, I'm concerned that an extra 10 GB of writes per day could significantly shorten its life.

I want to dedicate a storage medium to timeshift space that is optimum in terms of cost and lifespan for this type of high volume, temporary usage.  Of these storage media that are compatible with my notebook, which makes sense to use for this purpose:

- The internal SSD disk I'm using now?
- A USB flash drive?
- A SDHC card?

I've tried all of them and their performance is fast enough for this purpose, but I can't observe their longevity (until they fail).

Comment: Please define what concern / problem you are trying to solve with "optimize".   Better, depends on several things:  1.  Is your disk now fast enough to keep up with other work you are doing, as I assume it is?  2.   Is your SSD current technology that can easily withstand TB of writes per day for years?  I definitely would not use an SDHC card that is not made for massive writes.  But, other than that, why do you care?

Comment: I would not use any flash-based storage for repeated write operations.

Comment: 10Gb is 10 gigabit which is quite small, only 1/8 of 10GB. Gb and GB are very different

Comment: DaaBoss. I would like to preserve the lifespan of my SSD. 1. Yes. 2. I don't know. It's a Crucial MX300 disk.

Comment: I'll post something close to these details, once I can answer the question here:  Interesting -- I also recently bought a MX300, and I had been concerned about writing too much.  That is, until I read this article, which now leads me to believe that I shouldn't ever worry about my drive, or any of the current SSD technology: http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead  FYI, I DO an image backup every day, which only takes about 20 minutes, so not worried about it, even if it did die.

Comment: @Fixer1234 -- Might be better, but I don't know if you noticed his last comment... He already has the Crucial MX300 installed and is using it for that caching task!  So, I'm assuming that he was most concerned about destroying the drive he already had.  (Which is why I edited his question the way I did.  So if my edits are accepted, the revised question will show that.)

Comment: @DaaBoss, right. I take the question to be whether to continue to use the SSD, and possibly wear it out, vs. moving that caching to another medium so that the SSD is no longer used for that.

Comment: Related story: [Spotify is writing massive amounts of junk data to storage drives](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/11/for-five-months-spotify-has-badly-abused-users-storage-drives/)...

Comment: Thanks for revising my question in a more comprehensible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal concern with flash memory is the limited write life, after which the device dies and you could lose what's on it.  There are lots of posts about how SSDs are so effective at wear leveling that this isn't a real concern for typical usage.  Your case isn't typical usage, in several respects:

- You have a task that predictably and frequently writes an amount of data that could add up over time to a non-trivial impact on service life.
- You're looking for caching space.  If that's on a dedicated storage device and it's the only thing you put there, you don't need to be concerned about losing the data when the device fails.  If you use the device only for that, it's disposable.

Your SSD is the core of your system.  Maybe sticking the TimeShift space there will substantively affect the SSD's life and maybe it won't.  And you can protect yourself from data loss with backups.

However, **IF** it substantively shortens the SSD's life, it will be a pain in the butt when it fails.  It will take an investment of your time to reconstruct everything, it is likely to fail at an inopportune time, you will be out of commission until you replace the drive and restore everything, and the SSD will be expensive to replace.

So in this use case, why take any risk at all if there is a good alternative?  Fast flash drives and SD cards of small capacity can be purchased in multiple quantities dirt cheap on places like Amazon.  Use that for the TimeShift data.  Use it until it wears out, then toss it and stick in another one.

Worst case, it will fail at a time when you don't have a spare handy.  That won't put you out of commission because the computer operation won't be affected.  If you start going through "withdrawal" because you temporarily don't have access to TimeShift for the TV content, temporarily stick that on the SSD.  That short-term use won't have a material effect on the SSD.